# What is the mass and density distribution of a Schwarzchild black hole in the viewpoint of distant observer?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, mass-energy, density, event-horizon

According to [Schwarzschild metric:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric)

$$ c^2~\mathrm d\tau^2 = \left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)c^2 ~\mathrm dt^2 - \left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1}~\mathrm dr^2 - r^2\left(\mathrm d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta~\mathrm d\varphi^2 \right) $$

,where $r_s$ is Schwarzschild radius: $ r_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2} $

the density element $$ \rho(r) = \frac{\mathrm dm}{\mathrm dV} $$ becomes infinite on the event horizon if there is mass $$ \mathrm dm(r) > 0, r \rightarrow r_s, r>r_s $$very near at the outside of event horizon.

The density is then:

$$ \delta(r)_\infty = \frac{\mathrm dm_{r,\infty}}{\mathrm dV_{r,\infty}} = \frac{\mathrm dm_{r,\infty}}{(1-\frac{r_s}{r})^{1/2}(r~\mathrm dr~\mathrm  d\theta ~\sin\theta~\mathrm  d\varphi)} = \frac{\mathrm dm_{r,\infty}}{~\mathrm dV_{\infty,\infty} }\left(\sqrt{\frac{r}{r-r_s}}\right) $$

and at the limit $r \rightarrow r_s$:
$$ \delta(r)_{\infty}\to \infty , \text{when}~ (r \rightarrow r_s)~\text{and}~ (\mathrm dm_{r,\infty} > 0 ) $$

Note that this equation does not yet describe the density distribution. The mass element $$ \mathrm dm_{r,\infty} $$ is the mass inside volume element $$\mathrm  dV_{r,\infty} $$. In this equation, this can be anywhere between 0 and

$$ \text{max}(\mathrm dm_{r,\infty}) = \frac{M}{A_{BH}}= \frac{M}{4 \pi r_s^2} = \frac{c^4}{16\pi G^2M} $$

,where the maximum is in the situation when all of the mass of BH is concentrated into very thin layer above the event horizon. minimum 0 is the situation that all of the mass is inside the event horizon and none outside of it.

The Schwarzschild metric describes only the metric of spacetime outside of the Black Hole event horizon, not inside.

**Birkhoff's theorem** states that spacetime in the outerior of non-rotating thin spherical shell has Schwarzchild metric. And the interior of thin spherical shell has flat Minkowsky metric

$$ds^2 = c^2dt^2 - (dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)$$

And according to this theorem the interior metric of spherical mass distribution depends only on the spherical mass distribution that is inside the radius r. For example Spherical mass distribution with constant density has following metric:

$$ds^2 = -(1-\frac{2M(r)}{r})c^2dt^2 + (1 -\frac{2M(r)}{r})^{-1} dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\rho^2)$$

I don't know at the moment what is the general solution for interior metric of spherical mass distribution, but i have a guess that it depends largely on the equation of state of the matter, that determines what kind of density and pressure distribution the matter will eventually have when it is in dynamical and thermical equilibrium.

**My question is, what do we know about the mass distribution of density distribution of the black hole if it is observed by distant observer?** In other words, what are $$ \delta(r) , m(r) $$ of the ideal Schwarzschild Black Hole, if it is observed by observer that is infinitely far away from BH?

I see here two different kind of possiblities for BH mass distribution:

1. All or some of the mass is concentrated into very thin layer above the event horizon, when the density distribution is (more or less): $$ \rho (r) \rightarrow \delta (r_s) = \left \{ +\infty ,when r = r_s,= 0, when r > r_s \right \} $$
2. All of the mass is inside the event horizon,when the density distribution is:
   $$ \rho (r) = 0 , when r \geqslant r_s $$
   One possibility could be that all of the BH mass is concentrated into a very thin layer above the event horizon, and that there is no mass inside the event horizon. The reason why I think that it is possible is that the time dilation of BH becomes near infinity just above the horizon relative to the clock that is infinitely far away from the black hole and the matter stops falling down for this reason, if it is observed by observer that is far away from the black hole. Also the falling objects have nearly infinite radial length contraction relative to the metric infinitely far away from BH.

$$ \left(\frac{\tau_r }{\tau_\infty }\right) = \sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r}} \to 0, ~\text{when}~ (r \to r_s ) $$

$$ \left (  \frac{dr_{r}}{dr_{\infty}}\right ) = \sqrt{1 - \frac{r_s}{r}}\rightarrow 0, when (r\rightarrow r_s) $$

I am not sure what happens to the matter of BH in the birth of the black hole. Does the matter enter inside the event horizon or does it stay outside of the event horizon of the newborn black hole? IF the matter stays outside event horizon at the birth of BH, then it may be possible that all of the mass of BH is outside event horizon and the black hole is hollow inside in this sense.

On the other hand I am not sure about this, but the quantum tunneling effect and Heisenberg uncertainty principle may make possible that some of the particles can enter inside the event horizon.

So the question is, how the mass is distributed in ideal Schwarzchild Black hole in the viewpoint of distant observer?

Comment: How can the mass be in a shell above the event horizon? What would hold it there? What's the difference between inside and outside? The free falling observer can't tell such a difference. He will always be in an inertial system (with ever increasing tidal forces).

Comment: @CuriousOne "what would hold it there?" - this is answered in the third-to-last paragraph of the question. From the perspective of a distant observer, time dilation prevents matter from ever crossing the horizon, so there is a sense in which the matter *is* concentrated in a thin shell above the horizon. Of course this is not the case for an inertial observer falling into the hole. I imagine it's not very meaningful to define a function $\delta(r)$, but a good answer could explain why.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the distant observer sees. What matters is what holds the mass in the shell. So what force will hold the matter in the shell?

Comment: It is similar effect as following in the special relativity: If you observe a star and object that is falling to the star, and this system is travelling near light velocity, you would observe that the falling object will have less velocity and acceleration - because of the time dilation. The system would also have length contraction.

In schwarzschild metric, i think also the radial length dr will go infinitely small just above the event horizon if it is compared to dr at infinitely far away. The falling object will become thin in radial direction near the event horizon from this viewpoint.

Comment: It seems that OP is conflating an ideal Schwarzschild black hole with, say, a black hole with infalling matter.

Comment: Qmechanic i answered for CuriousOne into question in situation where infalling mass is very small m << M. And i asked in the topic question what is the mass density profile of ideal Schwarzschild Black Hole as a function of distance from the center : density(r)

Comment: Your metric has a mistake. The coefficient in front of $dr^2$ is $(1-\frac{r_s}{r})^{-1}$. You're missing the inverse.

Comment: cool, you fixed it. But now, notice that the inversed term is in the denominator of $dm/dV$, so you can move it to the numerator, thus it no longer becomes infinite at the event horizon

Comment: thanks! the metric equation is now ok. i think the density equation is also now ok.

Comment: Three comments:  (1)  The Schwarzchild metric is in fact a solution for both the exterior and interior of a black hole (at least in standard vacuum GR.)  (2)  The radial coordinate $r$ is not terribly well-behaved as $r \to r_s$, and I suspect that this ill-behaviour may be the source of your infinities.  If you really want to see what's happening at the horizon, a better choice would be [Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates) ...

Comment: (3) If you don't have a shell of infalling matter that you're treating as a "test mass", then the only meaningful way you can talk about the mass density in the spacetime is via the stress-energy tensor;  but Schwarzchild is a vacuum solution and so $T_{\mu \nu} = 0$ everywhere.

Comment: You can't use Schwarzschild coordinates at the horizon and expect to get results which mean anything, as the coordinates are singular there: you need to use some coordinates which are good at the horizon.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. 
I think you need thers Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates only if you observe the falling object in its own viewpoint. I can extend this question: is the mass of the black hole in this viewpoint above or is is of it below the event horizon. In this viewpoint the horizon is not singular. but should it be singular for distant observer?

I think the following:

1. for distant observer, nothing falls through event horizon because the infinite time dilation. 

2. The spacetime has also radial length contraction near the horizon which comes infinitely small.

Comment: In the perspective of falling observer, i think you can think of two different kind of situations: 1. the mass of the BH is all the time inside the event horizon and 2. The mass of the BH is some time in a thin layer above the event horizon, but at some given moment it may start to fall through the horizon - however in case 2. this has never happened in the point of view of distant observer and may never happen. (but i am not sure if quantum mechanical tunneling effect may  let this happen)

Comment: One issue seems to be this :There is so called ** Birkhoff's theorem ** that states that spherically symmetric thin mass shell has Schwarzchild metric outside the shell and flat or minkowsky metric inside the shell. Does this apply to Black hole as well if it is assumed that all the mass of the BH is in the very thin layer near to the horizon?

Comment: @Sami: Birkhoff's theorem applies to a black hole. But note that anything inside an infalling spherical shell experiences infinite time dilation from a point of view of an outside observer, so the shell falls on them in finite time from an inside observer's perspective.

Comment: @Peter Shor, are you saying that in the perspective of distant outside observer, the thin spherical shell of mass that has a slightly higher radius than Schwarchild radius for this mass, will continue to collapse and after some finite time the shell is inside the Schwarzchild radius? How does then the time dilation and radial length contraction behave inside this shell when r is nearly equal to Schwarchild radius? and will the factoral time dilation and length contraction be both 1 at the inner surface of the shell, while the outer surface follows Schwarzchild metric?

Comment: @Sami M: No; I'm saying that from the perspective of an ***inside*** observer who is at the center of the spherical shell of mass, it will collapse in a finite time. From an outside observer's viewpoint, the space inside the Schwartzchild radius is completely unobservable.

Comment: The inside observer experiences infinite time dilation with respect to the outside observer; the time dilation at the inner surface of the shell is not 1 (assuming you're taking the time at a large distance from the black hole to be the reference time).